# Sending parameters to proc in 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I want to write a subroutine in assembly 8086 which gets two arrays as parameters. 
How can I do it?
it is my code until now:

```
mov dl,[arr1]
mov dh, [arr2]
call adding
```

and this is my subroutine:

```
adding proc
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx


    mov [arrx],dl
    mov [arry],dh
       mov     cx, duplen 
       mov  bx, cx  ; point to lest significant digit!
       dec bx
    next_digit:

        ; add digits:
        mov     al, arrx[bx]
        adc     al, arry[bx]

        ; this is a very useful instruction that
        ; adjusts the value of addition
        ; to be string compatible
        aaa
        mov     sum[bx], al
        dec     bx
       loop    next_digit

    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax


    ret
```

what is wrong with it?

Comment: What do you mean *what is wrong with it?* What did you try, what results did you see, and what did you expect? FYI, the `AAA` instruction is for working with BCD (binary coded decimal) numbers. That is a number which encodes each decimal digit in consecutive *nibbles* (4-bit values or half-bytes). Are you using BCD?

Comment: yes , I am using BCD. the output is all zero instead of the sum value. I think arr1 and arr2 addresses are not correctly passed to proc.@lurker

Comment: OK, thanks. You should make it clear in your post that you're using BCD and what your results were. You can edit your post to do that.

Comment: So what should I do? Can you help me?@lurker

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass pointers to your arrays to the subroutine (which would be the right thing to do) but instead, you're only passing the first byte of each array in two different 8-bit registers. You need to pass the addresses in 16-bit registers.

Comment: I am new to this, but can you really address an array like he is doing it in his code: `mov al, arrx[bx]`?. I would have done it this way for an array of bytes: `mov al, [array + ebx]` ; array is the address pointing to the array in the memory, ebx is pointer to the array element (for example ebx=0 points to the first element of the array, ebx=1 to the second and so on).

Comment: @Blechdose it depends on the assembler he's using, which hasn't been stated. But first and foremost, the addresses must be passed as 16-bit values, assuming everything is in the same `ds` segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In stead of

```
mov dl,[arr1]
mov dh, [arr2]
call adding
```

use something like

```
mov si,arr1
mov di,arr2
call adding
```

with in the subroutine

```
clc           ;You forgot this !!!
next_digit:
; add digits:
mov al,[si+bx]
adc al,[di+bx]
aaa
mov sum[bx],al
dec bx
loop next_digit
```